# didDeselectItemAtIndexPath Dose not work -iOS

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

i have an collectionView, i tried to use this function but it dose not work in spite of i used cellForItemAtIndexPath,numberOfItemsInSection and they worked well :

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      NSLog(@"test");
}
```

any help please

Comment: Is the collection view's delegate set? https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/index.html

Comment: Did you set the delegate of your `UICollectionView` since the two methods you named are from the `dataSource` ?

Comment: yes i use this [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [_collectionView setDelegate:self];

Comment: @Larme : can you give me an exemple please ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      NSLog(@"test");
}
```

You have to read carefully - there are 2 very similar methods. One is called `didDeselect`... and one is called `didSelect`... ;-)

Comment: thank you for this :) but the problem it doesn't work too :(

Comment: Very strange. Why don't you zip your project and upload it, so that somebody can take a look?